# Cannot load Pytorch model in Pytorch mobile

Tags: android, pytorch

I attempt to load a model into an android app using the pytorch mobile flutter plugin which is just a wrapper for the android pytorch package, but when I attempt to load the model I get the following debug statement

```
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111): assets/models/fullap.pt is not a proper model
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111): com.facebook.jni.CppException: [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:222] . file not found: archive/constants.pkl
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111): (no backtrace available)
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111):     at org.pytorch.NativePeer.initHybrid(Native Method)
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111):     at org.pytorch.NativePeer.<init>(NativePeer.java:25)
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111):     at org.pytorch.Module.load(Module.java:25)
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111):     at org.pytorch.Module.load(Module.java:35)
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111):     at io.fynn.pytorch_mobile.PyTorchMobilePlugin.onMethodCall(PyTorchMobilePlugin.java:58)
E/PyTorchMobile( 8111):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
```

I saved the model using torch.save(model, path) after loading it from a state dict. I also tried to resave the model. Any ideas as to what the problem may be? the model is not quantized as of right now.

Comment: It might be a problem with different Pytorch versions like mentioned [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/fynnmaarten/flutter_pytorch_mobile/issues/19). I tried to change the according dependencies to the newest version but it still doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

```
file not found: archive/constants.pkl
```

Make sure you've set the right path of the model.

Comment: That was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, different pytorch versions between model saving and model loading might be a problem.

The solution in my case was to optimize the model for torchscript as mentioned in the [pytorch mobile docs](https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/#1-model-preparation). Now I can load the models successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you need convert first.

1. convert pytorch model to pytorch script format(ptscript)
2. convert ptscript to pytorch mobile format(ptmobile)

example invoke:

```
export_ptscript_and_ptmobile(mel,
                             (1, 840),
                             'mel_ptscript.pt',
                             'mel_ptmobile.pt'):
```

method python:

```
import torch
import torch.utils.mobile_optimizer as mobile_optimizer


def export_ptscript(model, pt_model_uri):
    # save ptmobile
    batch_size = 1
    sequence_length = 840
    input_shape = (batch_size, sequence_length)
    export_ptscript_with_input(model, input_shape, pt_model_uri)


def export_ptscript_with_input(model, input_shape, pt_model_uri):
    # .pt
    # Trace the model with random data.
    dummy_input = torch.ones(input_shape).detach()
    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, dummy_input)
    torch_script = traced_model(dummy_input)
    torch.jit.save(traced_model, pt_model_uri)


# https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/mobile_interpreter.html
# https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/attributeerror-module-torch-utils-has-no-attribute-mobile-optimizer/93736
def export_ptmobile(ptscript_model_uri, ptmobile_name):
    # 
    model = torch.jit.load(ptscript_model_uri)

    # 
    mobile_model = mobile_optimizer.optimize_for_mobile(model)

    # 
    mobile_model._save_for_lite_interpreter(ptmobile_name)


def export_ptscript_and_ptmobile(model, input_shape, ptscript_name, ptmobile_name):
    export_ptscript_with_input(model, input_shape, ptscript_name)
    export_ptmobile(ptscript_name, ptmobile_name)
```